# unknown column in on clause error in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

```
mysql> select * FROM borrower;
+--------+------------+---------+--------------+
| cardno | name       | address | phone        |
+--------+------------+---------+--------------+
|      1 | A          | nj,usa  | 111-222-333 |
|      2 | B          | NY,USA  | 444-555-666 |
|      3 | C          | nj,usa  | 777-888-999 |
+--------+------------+---------+--------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * FROM bookloans;
+--------+----------+--------+------------+------------+
| bookid | branchid | cardno | dateout    | duedate    |
+--------+----------+--------+------------+------------+
|      1 |        1 |      1 | 2014-04-01 | 2014-08-01 |
+--------+----------+--------+------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

cardno in bookloans is foreign key for cardno in borrower. C

Now I am trying to execute following SQL query:

```
mysql> select name,address from borrower full join bookloans
  on bookloans.cardno = borrower.cardno
  group by cardno having count(bookid)=0;
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'borrower.cardno' in 'on clause'
```

I don't understand the error as borrower table does have column called cardno. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks,
Sunil

Answer (score 5):

MySQL does not support `full join` syntax. So the word `full` in this query is being interpreted as a table alias, as if you had done a query like:

```
... FROM borrower AS `full`
    JOIN bookloans ...
```

Then subsequently when you reference `borrower.cardno`, it's confused because it thought you wanted to refer to the borrower table using an alias `full`.

I know it's a really dumb bug in the MySQL parser. I logged a bug about it (http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=69858). You should click "affects me" on that bug.

UPDATE: [MySQL 8.0.31 finally supports `FULL` as a reserved keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-31.html#mysqld-8-0-31-sql-syntax). MySQL still doesn't implement full outer join, but at least you won't get surprised by this bug. If you do want to use the word `full` as a table alias, you must delimit it (as you would if you used any other reserved keyword as an identifier).

---

Re your comment:

The common way to do a full outer join in MySQL is:

```
SELECT ...
FROM borrower LEFT OUTER JOIN bookloans USING (cardno)
UNION
SELECT ...
FROM borrower RIGHT OUTER JOIN bookloans USING (cardno)
```

However, in your case, I don't think you actually need a full outer join. You're using `GROUP BY COUNT(bookid) = 0` so it seems like you're looking for a left outer join where there is no matching row in bookloans:

```
SELECT name, address FROM borrower
LEFT OUTER JOIN bookloans USING (cardno)
WHERE bookloans.cardno IS NULL;
```

Comment: so there is no way to do a full join in mysql?